# Handling registry key changes

Tags: c#

I'm having to use a `Process.Start` in C# in order to run cmd.exe as another user which will have rights to change the registry value in question. However, not entirely sure how to get this working/handle it correctly.

```
        ProcessStartInfo processAdmin;
        processAdmin = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processAdmin.UseShellExecute = false;
        processAdmin.Password = secureString;
        processAdmin.UserName = "admin";
        processAdmin.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        processAdmin.Arguments = "/C reg add HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon -v Shell -t REG_SZ -d explorer.exe /f";
        processAdmin.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32";
        Process.Start(processAdmin);
```

Main problem I guess being the spaces in the `ProcessAdmin.Arguements`, specifically in the registry path i.e. `\\Windows NT\\`, in a standard cmd.exe I would wrap that in `"...."` but not entirely sure how to wrap that about in C, or whether there is a much MUCH nicer way of doing this. Note, the application will be running under a standard user, but I need the registry key change to run as an `admin` acccount using the secureString to allow reg changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just add double quotes around your Winlogon path and it should work.

```
processAdmin.Arguments = "/C reg add \"HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\" -v Shell -t REG_SZ -d explorer.exe /f";
```

Comment: Meaning you can't compile ? It compiles fine on my side.

Comment: Okay, it compiles, but doesn't change the registry key :( cmd.exe appears for a brief second but then closes down instantly.

Comment: You can see the output of your cmd command by setting `processAdmin.RedirectStandardError` and `processAdmin.RedirectStandardOutput` to true and then reading both streams : `proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`.  And you need to get a reference to the process when you start it : `var p = Process.Start(processAdmin);`